# Prevent rounding of numbers when converting dictionary into dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, rounding

I wrote a code where I first create a dictionary and then convert it to a dataframe. The dictionary contains lat and lon data. My issue is that during the transformation into the dataframe, the lon and lat data is rounded.

The code looks like this:

```
geodata = {'01067': (13.7210676148814, 51.0600336463379, u'Dresden'),
        '01069': (13.7389066401609, 51.039558876083, u'Dresden'),
        '01097': (13.7439674110642, 51.0667452412037, u'Dresden'),
        '01099': (13.8289798683304, 51.0926193047084, u'Dresden'),
        '01109': (13.7619645364861, 51.1201009324663, u'Dresden'),
        '01127': (13.733347378178, 51.0796304130158, u'Dresden'),
        '01129': (13.7274104697459, 51.0967944759693, u'Dresden'),
        '01139': (13.6911443969423, 51.0805574259239, u'Dresden'),
        '01157': (13.6708047478723, 51.0643076931977, u'Dresden')}

postal_data1= pd.DataFrame(geodata) # at this point the numbers are rounded

postal_data1 =  postal_data1.T
postal_data1['zip'] = postal_data1.index
postal_data1.columns = ['lon', 'lat', 'city', 'zip']
postal_data1 = postal_data1.reindex(columns=['zip', 'lat', 'lon', 'city'])
postal_data1 = postal_data1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

At the end the dataframe looks like this:

```
postal_data1.head()
 
     zip      lat      lon     city
0  01067    51.06  13.7211  Dresden
1  01069  51.0396  13.7389  Dresden
2  01097  51.0667   13.744  Dresden
3  01099  51.0926   13.829  Dresden
4  01109  51.1201   13.762  Dresden
```

Does anyone has an idea how I can prevent the rounding of the lat and lon data?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That's not needed. The printed head() is just a representation pandas shows in prints. Altough the default data precision is higher, you can modify the representation using:

```
pd.set_option("display.precision", 10)
```

Comment: but when I access the dataframe via the variable explorer (I use spyder), it also shows only the rounded numbers. Wouldn't that mean that the numbers were indeed rounded?

Comment: it could use the representation anyway, you can check by accessing a single cell value (with .value)